# Byte arrays memory not released

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm having a problem with memory usage in C#. I've been searching around and all I found is about GC, and not to run it manually.

Here is my code. It simply replaces the bytes of one file with another. After its job, it stays in memory and never gets cleaned out. I know GC only runs when needed, but in my case it never runs until I force it manually. The file it reads is around 400-500MB.

```
var fileByte = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("text");
var byteToReplace = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("taxt");

int index = SearchBytes(fileByte, byte); //get index of the byte
if (index != 0)
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy(fileByte, 0, fileByte, 0, index);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(byteToReplace, 0, fileByte, index, byteToReplace.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(fileByte, index + byte.Length,
            fileByte, index + byteToReplace.Length,
            fileByte.Length - index - byte.Length);
}

File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, fileByte); 

fileByte = null; //set it as null
```

Any idea how I get around it?

Comment: Do you have any problem with this, like an `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: `it never runs until I force it manually` - which [is correct](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203).

Comment: No need to set `fileByte` to `null` if that's the end of its containing scope (in particular, if that's the end of the method). Once there are no outstanding references to the array that `fileByte` referred to, then that object is _eligible fir collection_. If it's truly 500 MB, then it's a _large object_ and it will only be collected during the next full GC. It may make sense to call `GC.Collect`. But it probably makes more sense to not call `File.ReadAllBytes`, and instead read the file block by block

Comment: Hi Klaus Gütter no theres no exception.
Hi Flydog57, Yes, it is truly 500MB. Program memory increased by 500MB and it stays like that forever. Edits: I also think about that, to use block of chunks instead but it is slower.

Comment: So, what is the problem? is your computer running out of memory?

Comment: @JonasH Not really, but I tested on the virtual machine that has 4GB of RAM, and it didn't release the memory. That is the issue, I guess. but well I might be wrong and GC only runs when you run out of RAM.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that the GC does not feel any reason to run since there is plenty of memory available. Once you start approaching the limits of available memory I would expect the GC to free it. If you are worried about memory leaks I would suggest using a memory profiler, that should tell you if you have problems with your code.

Comment: For some reason I feel using a `using` here might help possibly.

Comment: Yes Timothy, that was what I did but it is not as fast as `ReadAllBytes`, maybe I should stick to chunk of bytes for now.

Comment: The `using` keyword only works with types that implement `IDisposable`. Arrays only use managed memory, (which gets garbage collected) so there's nothing to _Dispose_. If you do this only once, feel free to call `GC.Collect` after you're done. That will _schedule_ a GC. Don't call `WaitForPendingFinalizers`: just let the GC happen when it happens. However, if this is part of an app (like a service or a web app) that is handling many things at once, put more thought into it before making a decision that is usually the responsibility of the garbage collector

Comment: Basically I read your question as "why GC does not run when it does not need to run. I find it wrong and wish it to detect my desires and run accordingly". I'm not really sure what exactly you expect to happen and why you'd like GC to run when it is not needed.

Comment: In the last 20 years, I've called `GC.Collect` twice in apps. In both cases, the apps did a lot of work, spinning off a lot of garbage and were about to go mostly dormant. It seemed like a good time to reduce my memory footprint - something I knew, but the GC didn't. My approach to your app would be to reduce the use of the Large Object Heap, by reading stuff in block by block. Reducing LOH usage is something worth worrying about. Worrying about when the GC runs isn't

Comment: A better question is why you are loading a whole 500MB file into memory at once. It's unnecessary, you should be looping through a `FileStream` looking for your data, and streaming that straight back out. Also `Buffer.BlockCopy(fileByte, 0, fileByte, 0, index);` make no sense